# trouble with multiple CustomMarker Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having issues with a second CustomMarker. I can see the paths on the map, but the anchor points are not showing up with my custom image. What am I missing?

My code for the second Custom Marker is:

```
/* ***** Begin CustomMarker Toekomst ***** */
function CustomMarkerToekomst(latlng, map, marker_id, hovercard) {
  this.latlng_ = latlng;
  this.marker_id = marker_id;
  this.hovercard_content = hovercard;
  this.setMap(map);
}

CustomMarkerToekomst.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

CustomMarkerToekomst.prototype.draw = function() {
  var me = this;
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV'); 
        div.id=me.marker_id;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
  }
  var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (point) {
      div.className = 'map-marker-toekomst show-hovercard';
      div.style.left = (point.x-6) + 'px';
      div.style.top = (point.y-23) + 'px';
      $(div).attr('data-hovercard-content', me.hovercard_content);

  }
};

CustomMarkerToekomst.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

CustomMarkerToekomst.prototype.getPosition = function() {
 return this.latlng_;
};
/* ***** Eind CustomMarker Toekomst ***** */
```

My css for the div 'map-marker-toekomst' is; I have verified that the background does exist.:

```
.map-marker-toekomst {
position: absolute;
width: 21px;
height: 25px;
background: url(removed/img/mapmarker_blue.png) no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

My results are populated from a database query from php into the javascript as:

```
   echo "            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(" . $row['latitudedecimal'] . "," .  
$row['longitudedecimal'] . ");\n";
   echo "            overlay = new CustomMarkerToekomst(pos, map, \"" . $row['marker'] 
. "\", '" . $row['luchthavennaam'] . "');\n";
   echo "            overlay.setMap(map);\n";
   echo "            bounds.extend(pos);\n";
   echo "      \n";
```

I have a similiar CustomMarker just above this script which works fine, it's this second one that is the problem.

Comment: Can you provide just the code to replicate the problem? Or a jsfiddle that shows the issue?  Or a link to a live map that does?

Comment: hi geocodezip, for whatever reason nothing I tried worked in regards to the above. However, if I changed it to CustomMarkerAankomst, added the appropriate information in my css, etc it works... it's not what it should be called, but since 99.9% of people will never experience the html code, it shouldn't matter.